# Three possible ways to read a file and assign file values to variable

Tags: c

I have 3 scenarios to pass information of a input file to variables in my C code. 2 of them work, and one of them, which is what I need, doesn't work, and I don't know how to fix it.

Inside the input file:

```
23.65
47.93
2
7
```

**The First Scenario:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

long double* read_input_file(long double*);

int main (){

    long double par[2];

    read_input_file(par);
    printf("par[0] = %Lf \npar[1] = %Lf \n\n", par[0], par[1]); 

    getchar();
    return 0;
}

long double* read_input_file(long double* p){
    FILE* input;

    input = fopen("input.txt","r");
    fscanf(input,"%Lf\n%Lf",&p[0],&p[1]);
    
    printf("par[0]_in = %Lf \npar[1]_in = %Lf\n", p[0], p[1]);

    fclose(input);

    return p;
}
```

The Output:

```
par[0]_in = 23.650000
par[1]_in = 47.930000
par[0] = 23.650000
par[1] = 47.930000
```

This scenario does the job, however it limits the range of variable types I can use as my function is typed as long double.

**Then, I tried the Second Scenario:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

long double par[2];
int b, a;

void read_input_file(void);

int main (){

    read_input_file();
    printf("par[0] = %Lf \npar[1] = %Lf \n", par[0], par[1]);
    printf("a = %d \nb = %d \n", a, b);

    getchar();
    return 0;
}

void read_input_file(void) {
    FILE* input;

    input = fopen("input.txt","r");

    fscanf(input,"%Lf\n%Lf",&par[0],&par[1]);
    fscanf(input,"%d\n%d",&a,&b);

    printf("par[0]_in = %Lf \npar[1]_in = %Lf\n", par[0], par[1]);
    printf("b_in = %d \nb_in = %d\n", a, b);
    
    fclose(input);
}
```

The output:

```
par[0]_in = 23.650000
par[1]_in = 47.930000
b_in = 2
b_in = 7
par[0] = 23.650000
par[1] = 47.930000
a = 2
b = 7
```

This one is more flexible and I can specify the type of variable each number of my input file is assigned, however it needs the usage of global variables, something I'm trying to avoid.

**Then I tried the Third Scenario:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

void read_variables(long double*, int, int);

int main (){
    long double par[2];
    int a;
    int b;

    read_variables(par, a, b);
    printf("par[0] = %Lf \npar[1] = %Lf \n", par[0], par[1]);
    printf("a = %d \nb = %d \n", a, b);

    getchar();
    return 0;
}

void read_variables(long double*p, int A, int B){
    FILE* input;

    input = fopen("input.txt","r");

    fscanf(input,"%Lf\n%Lf",&p[0],&p[1]);
    fscanf(input,"%d\n%d",&A,&B);

    printf("par[0]_in = %Lf \npar[1]_in = %Lf\n", p[0], p[1]);
    printf("a_in = %d \nb_in = %d\n\n", A, B);
    fclose(input);
}
```

The Output:

```
par[0]_in = 23.650000
par[1]_in = 47.930000
a_in = 2
b_in = 7

par[0] = 23.650000
par[1] = 47.930000
a = 1
b = 1922719232
```

What I tried to do in this third one is to avoid global variables, and in the same time use a function that reads the input file and assign the numbers there in a group of variables that are not of the same type.

I already tried to use int* a; int* b instead and it did not work.

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: 3rd scenario: First call `read_variables(par, &a, &b);` it needs `read_variables(long double*p, int* A, int* B)` then `fscanf(input,"%d\n%d",A,B);` also `printf("a_in = %d \nb_in = %d\n\n", *A, *B);`

Comment: par, b and a  should not be global variables, that's very poor practice. The second scenario works because `fscanf(input,"%d\n%d",&a,&b);` addresses the globals a and b. The 3rd scenarion doesn't work because `fscanf(input,"%d\n%d",&A,&B);` addresses the local variables A and B, which are thrown away once the `read_variables` function is over.

Comment: why not `void read_variables(long double*, long double*, int*, int*);`?